# Find in which polygon certain coordinate (latitude, longitude) lies with MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-maps, aggregation-framework, geospatial

Let's say 100 documents (so to say polygons) in a collection named **Areas** with this structure:

```js
{
  ...otherFields,
  commonName: "Butwal",
  area: {
    type: "Polygon",
    coordinates: [
      {
        latitude: 27.66779856,
        longitude: 83.4668095
      },
      ...
      ...
      {
        latitude: 27.66779856,
        longitude: "83.4668095
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now I would like to find in which of those document(so to say polygon) this coordinate lies:

```js
{
  latitude: 27.683793,
  longitude: 83.458689
}
```

**with the help of MongoDB either aggregation or other operators please help!!**

**OR if I can do with javascript(NodeJS) in very performance way**

**OR with some google maps API**

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    <location field>: {
        $geoWithin: {
            $geometry: {
                type: <"Polygon" or "MultiPolygon"> ,
                coordinates: [ <coordinates> ]
             }
         }
    }
}
```

For more information follow this link **https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am supposed to pass the location from the client and all the polygons are stored in database in collection named ```Areas``` now I would like to know in which document(polygon) that co-ordinate lies

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$geoIntersects` for this:

```
db.collection.find({
        geometry: {
          $geoIntersects: {
            $geometry: {type: 'Point', coordinates: inputCoordinates},
          },
        },
      })
```

To find the polygon document that includes the inputCoordinates point